# Showing this Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token for Facebook SSO integration

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing facebook Single sign on integration but its showing this warning and nothing is happening on button click it just shows progress dialog and then homescreen is appearing after exiting the app. I had not uploaded the apk on playstore and want to make the app working for debug mode. please help.
Here is my code:

```
public class SplashActivityButton extends Activity {
        Button fb_login_button;
        public AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;

        public Facebook facebook = new Facebook("my_appid");
        private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
        GraphUser user;
        boolean flag = true;
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();


        Context context = this;

        private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
        private final String PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY = "my_package_name:PendingAction";

        private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

        private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
        private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreenbtn);
            fb_login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
            fb_login_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // start Facebook Login
                    Global.flagLogin = true;
                    openActiveSession(SplashActivityButton.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
                        // callback when session changes state
                        @Override
                        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                            if (state.isOpened()) {
                                {
                                    Log.e("sessionopened", "true");
                                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                            if (user != null) {
                                                String firstName = user.getFirstName();
                                                String lastName = user.getLastName();
                                                String id = user.getId();
                                                String email = user.getProperty("email").toString();

                                                Log.e("facebookid", id);
                                                Log.e("firstName", firstName);
                                                Log.e("lastName", lastName);
                                                Log.e("email", email);
                                                Global.guestuser = email;
                                                Global.getUserName = user.getName();

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }, permissions);


                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're either missing the application ID or the client token.

For mor detailed information, provide your information first, so we'd be able to help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: have you created proper hashkeys for your application?

Comment: You must be missing session handling in ONActivityResult() of your Activity.Post your Code

Comment: I generated the application id from developer.facebook.com and then generated the keyhash via keytool command using cmd prompt and even i did it via coding and the keyhash is correct. I added the app id in strings.xml that is located in my project res folder even i added the meta tag in the application tab in androidmanifest.xml file. Is there anything else where i forgot ?

Comment: @HetalPatel have you created debug keyhash or using keystore keyhash of your application?

Comment: @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }

Comment: Just edit your question with your Implementation

Comment: Actually i was quite confused with the keyhash to first i created keystore keyhash and used that then it was not working, then again i created debug keyhash but then too its not working showing error message in device that this keyhash does not match...

Comment: @HetalPatel ya for debugging mode you have to use debug keystore. I suggest you to use Simple Facebook api, its very easy to use and working very fine also.

Comment: @HetalPatel code looks fine I think, can you please try with Simple Facebook?

Comment: Simple facebook ?? that is what i had done

Comment: @HetalPatel yes, its an third party api but it contains main facebook api in back side, so developer can use simple facebook that means they are using main facebook api indirectly, but SF is very easy to use.

Comment: Actually this is working for my previous 3 apps but in this one i am facing such problem and not getting any solution for the bug.

Comment: @hetalPatel its ok, I never did like this way, in my organization all the people are using SF, so I am sorry

Comment: @HetalPatel if you want some sample code for SF then I can help you. Let me know if you need it.